# "How does accepting an answer work?" Image that shows "accepting answer" is wrong

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, meta-faq

The image at the FAQ entry [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about) isn't obvious.

It says "To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green," but the image that it shows is of someone voting an answer up. Is this intentional? It has survived a lot of edits so I'm afraid to edit it myself for this reason.

I think it should show an image with accepted answer checkmark filled in as if it is actually accepted.

Comment: Or a two-frame animated GIF.

Comment: Some people just aren't that aware of the **huge** empty checkmark under the votes.

Answer (score 2):

It shows what it looks like before accepting an answer that has previously been upvoted (as most accepted answers probably should be).  I understood it immediately, but I'd already accepted answers on SO before I'd seen it.

If you want to clarify it, preserve the free hand, since it's referenced elsewhere on MSO. :)

Done:
[image]

Comment: yes, but it doesn't show what it looks like afterward. When I first read it I thought it was cut into two frames with the first frame being before being accepted and the second frame as the intention of accepting the answer (where it is actually upvoted)

Comment: So... soulless. A freehand cries in pain.